# "Алексей Максимович Горький" - допустимо ли?

Tags: литература, грамотная-речь, смысл

Возникли сомнения, можно ли называть Максима Горького (Алексея Максимовича Пешкова) Алексеем Максимовичем Горьким? Ведь фактически Алексей Горький - это совсем другой человек.

Answer (score 3):

Мысль-то правильная. Нельзя создавать этакого гомункулуса, сшитого из разных частей реального имени и псевдонима.
Но в отношении Горького (и еще некоторых авторов помельче, не помню сейчас), а также многих революционеров (начиная от Ленина-Сталина), такой симбиоз узаконен многолетней практикой - причем при наличии гласного или негласного согласия самого деятеля. Такие псевдонимы перерастали своё обычное предназначение, становились партийной кличкой (сейчас бы сказали "позывной") и постепенно заменяли фамилию. Имя-отчество псевдонима при этом обычно выходило из использования. 
Так что тут все законно.

Answer (score 2):

Особенность в том, что в литературном псевдониме "Максим Горький" *не было отчества*, и люди, общавшиеся с **писателем Горьким**, всегда называли его "**Алексеем Максимовичем**" - альтернативы не было. Такое естественное соединение зафиксировалось в статьях, мемуарах (можно легко представить себе строки: "... я встретился с Горьким, и Алексей Максимович поведал..." - как тут автору или читателю не ассоциировать одно с другим?) и прочих дошедших до нас письменных материалах. Более того, по всей видимости, формально имя и фамилия не менялись: сын Горького звался "Максим Алексеевич Пешков". Здесь имеет место полная противоположность случаю *Корнея Ивановича Чуковского* (Николай Васильевич Корнейчуков), псевдоним которого формализовался настолько, что имя и фамилия из него отразились на фамилии и отчестве детей, а настоящее имя писателя осталось в биографической литературе.

Comment: Знаете, что мне не нравится в Ваших рассуждениях? То, что литературных псевдонимов с отчествами вообще почти не бывает (случаи автора-мистификации типа Козьмы Пруткова - не в счет). Но псевдонимы стали фамилиями в единичных случаях. Близкий Горькому по времени и месту Демьян Бедный так и остался  Ефимом Алексеевич Придворовым, Набоков Владимиром Владимировичем Сириным не стал. Да вот из немаленького списка наиболее известных псевдонимов - ничего подходящего. Или псевдоним - или имя. Никакого кровосмешения. http://arzamas.academy/materials/321.